# syntax error in insert into command. The error could be while entering date value

Tags: java, ms-access, project

```
private void jButton2MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        conn = Connect.ConnectDB();
        Object selected1 = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
        Object selected2 = jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
        selected1.toString();
        selected2.toString();
        String sql= "insert into Table1 ("
        +"ID,"
        +"Bill_No,"
        +"[Vendor_Name],"
        +"[Expense],"
        +"Amount,"
        +"TDS%,"

        +"Status,"
        +"Cheque_Stages,"
        +"Cno1,"+"Cno2,"+"Cno3,"+"Cno4,"
        +"[Cdate1],"+"[Cdate2],"+"[Cdate3],"+"[Cdate4],"
        +"[CAmount1],"+"[CAmount2],"+"[CAmount3],"+"[CAmount4],"+"[Purpose],"
        +"TDSamount,"+"Appamount)"
        +"values("+jTextField1.getText()+"','"+jTextField2.getText()+"','"+jTextField3.getText()
        +"','"+jTextField4.getText()
        +"','"+jTextField5.getText()+"','"+jTextField6.getText()+"','"//+"','"+selected1+"','"+selected2
        +"','"+jTextField9.getText()+"','"+jTextField10.getText()+"','"+jTextField11.getText()
        +"','"+jTextField12.getText()
        +"','"+jTextField15.getText()+"','"+jTextField16.getText()+"','"+jTextField17.getText()
        +"','"+jTextField18.getText()
        +"','"+jTextField7.getText()+"','"+jTextField19.getText()+"','"+jTextField20.getText()
        +"','"+jTextField21.getText()+"')"+jTextField8.getText()
        +"','"+jTextField13.getText()+"','"+jTextField14.getText()+"')";
        try{
            pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.executeQuery();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "SAVED");
            conn.close();
            UpdateJTable();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }
```

i get error saying syntax error in insert statement along with this-

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.createSQLException(JdbcOdbc.java:6964)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.standardError(JdbcOdbc.java:7121)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc.SQLPrepare(JdbcOdbc.java:4837)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcOdbcConnection.java:475)
    at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcOdbcConnection.java:443)
    at application.NewMDIApplication.jButton2MouseClicked(NewMDIApplication.java:1049)
    at application.NewMDIApplication.access$1900(NewMDIApplication.java:17)
    at application.NewMDIApplication$20.mouseClicked(NewMDIApplication.java:466)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6519)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6281)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4872)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4501)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4698)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:718)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: format code properly and let us know what issue you facing ?

Comment: just did. i think the error might be while saving the date.

Comment: Inspect the `sqlObject` field of the `PreparedStatement` in your debugger and you will see the SQL that it's trying to execute. If you can't see the problem in the SQL, then update the question with it. As an aside, you should be using parameters rather than dumping data directly into the SQL manually, which leaves you exposed to SQL injection.

Comment: Have you printed out the statement so it can be read properly?
If no please do so and post the result. it is easy for the eye t catch the syntax error whithout those "" and + and lines.
Thanks.

Comment: so should i save every particular data i am getting from the textfield into a seperate string and then enter it into the database ? @JonK

Comment: No - you should just use the PreparedStatement interface properly. A basic example would be: `PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO someTable (col1) VALUES (?)"); stmt.setString(1, "My col1 value");`

Comment: can you please edit it for any 2 fields in the code i've given ? it would really be a great help. 
I tried doing it myself, showing some errors again. 
and it is asking for result set.

Comment: you are missing an opening `'` in the start of the values declaration: `"values("+jTextField1.getText()+"'` should be `"values('"+jTextField1.getText()+"'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by replacing all `jTextFieldX.getText()` with `""` and printing the string you will get:

`insert into Table1 (ID,Bill_No,[Vendor_Name],[Expense],Amount,TDS%,Status,Cheque_Stages,Cno1,Cno2,Cno3,Cno4,[Cdate1],[Cdate2],[Cdate3],[Cdate4],[CAmount1],[CAmount2],[CAmount3],[CAmount4],[Purpose],TDSamount,Appamount)values(','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','')','','')`

[See here https://ideone.com/lik4SR](https://ideone.com/lik4SR)

There are multiple things wrong here:

- I dont know if `TDS%` is a valid column name or if it just needs to be enclosed in `[]`
- 23 parameters vs. 21? supplied values (varying depending on how you treat the fourth mistake)
- a missing `'` in the beginning of the values-part
- a incorrectly placed `)` in the middle of the values
- everything is enclosed as string, nothing is representing a date or a number as the field names would suggest
- you are escaping not a sinlge input -> sql injection

You therefore need to

- fix the query syntax
- fix the number of values
- fix the value types, remove the `'` for numbers and dates, add `#` for dates

Comment: i've enclosed TDS% within [], missing ' issued is resolved, in place of incorrectly placed ) there was to be a ' which ive taken care of.
date variables ive enclosed within [] so as to accept it as string

now it says no of query values and destination fields are not the same, as for the 23 parameters vs 21. here, the two problematic fields are the text which im trying to get from two combobox's

Comment: @AnmolKhanna then leave the two out for now and just write `""` instead of their values. But that is at least a far better error message. Lets see what the error message says afterwards.

Comment: no of query values and destination fields are not the same.
the same error message

Comment: @AnmolKhanna then go ahead and count the values and the destination fields - i have no idea what your code looks like right now, but apparently you still have too few values specified...

Comment: i am passing values from 21 textfields to 21 queries and left the other two combobox's "".

Comment: @AnmolKhanna Please add a `System.out.println(sql);` before the `prepareStatement`. Then post that printed value.

Comment: too long the error to post, the first few lines says-

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.util.HashMap to java.util.List
 at java.lang.Class.cast(Class.java:3176)
 at org.jdesktop.beansbinding.Binding.convertForward(Binding.java:1312)

Comment: and then-

insert into Table1 (ID,Bill_No,[Vendor_Name],[Expense],Amount,[TDS%],Cheque_Stages,Cno1,Cno2,Cno3,Cno4,[Cdate1],[Cdate2],[Cdate3],[Cdate4],CAmount1,CAmount2,CAmount3,CAmount4,[Purpose],TDSamount,Appamount,Status)values('3','1234','anmol','personal','50000','4','','1234','2345','3456','4567','2015-06-24 00:00:00.0','2015-06-25 00:00:00.0','2015-06-26 00:00:00.0','2015-06-27 00:00:00.0','20000','10000','10000','10000','single','2000.0','48000.0')

Comment: @AnmolKhanna i count 22 values for 23 fields.

Comment: ohh yes i saw that. status' value i wasnt passing. that was one of the combobox which i removed. I am getting a datatype mismatch in criteria expression now (._.' )

Comment: @AnmolKhanna yes, i was 100% sure you will get that error now - now comes the part where all the values you pass have to be of the right type, numbers must NOT be wrapped in `'`, date values must be wrapped as Gustav wrote, etc.

Comment: okay. now my values are of correct type. It asks me for a resultset value when i insert some values. if i initialize my resultset variable to null, the data is entered into the database, but comes a dialog saying "NoResultSet was Produced"

Comment: I can successfully add data to my database. But instead of showing me a "saved" message(which i have added) it shows NoResultSet was produced/

Comment: @AnmolKhanna but if you check for the data in the database it actually has been added? I do not know anything about that unfortunately, maybe ask a new question with the now correct query and the strange error message.

Comment: i have a table of all the values just next to my frame. yes, the data gets added in it, but instead of showing me 'saved' message, shows me that error.

Comment: cannot use rs = pst.executeUpdate() shows some error.
anyways, you've been of great help. Thankyou so much !
can i have your email id please ? :)

Comment: @AnmolKhanna would you care to enlighten why you chose to unaccept my answer? while Gustav's answer is definitely not bad it surely did not solve your problem!

Comment: ohh i did accept your answer.
your help did solve my problem !

Answer (score 0):

For the CDateN fields, you will have to supply formatted string expressions of your date values. I'm not familiar with Java, but the resulting string for the date of today should be `#2015/06/24#` so those parts of the SQL will look like:

```
... "sometext",#2015/06/24#,#2015/06/01#,"someothertext" ...
```

Comment: i am trying to get the date from a textfield. should i use this method there too ?

Comment: Yes. That's Access SQL.

Comment: while i am entering the date, then should i use the # ?

Comment: You will never get the user to accept that, so have a date picker or the like that returns a date value in Java. Then convert/format that value to a string as shown.

Comment: tried using jDatePicker, didnt work. Whenever i drag it from palatte to my panel, it doesnt show up.

Comment: Sorry, can't tell. I don't use Java.